# Homogeneous values on levels in tree algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, treeview, swt, jface

Consider a tree with 3 levels: L1, L2, L3 (but this is just a particular case, for question convenience; there is no limitation on the number of levels and children on each level).

Each level holds a key and a value (e.g. `[string, integer]`).

**Algorithm**: If the direct children all have the same value, then don't display those values on child level, but on parent level. **Only leaves can have values, the parents just represent data depending on leaf content**.

**My solution**: I changed my mind. I need a general solution, excluding the JFace `LabelProvider`s. I traverse the tree in post-order, and keep values in a map. I would prefer to keep only entries that don't have a *null* value (i.e. level has something to display). Performance is critical.

```
    Case 1           Case 2           Case 3
--------------   --------------   --------------  
L1         | 1   L1         | -   L1         | - 
|-- L2     | -   |-- L2     | 1   |-- L2     | -
|   |-- L3 | -   |   |-- L3 | -   |   |-- L3 | 1
|   +-- L3 | -   |   +-- L3 | -   |   +-- L3 | 2
+-- L2     | -   +-- L2     | 2   +-- L2     | -
    |-- L3 | -       |-- L3 | -       |-- L3 | 1
    +-- L3 | -       +-- L3 | -       +-- L3 | 2
```

<strike>**Limitation**: I only have access to one level at a time, since I'm using content and label providers to fill in the tree. For example, I have a callback method called `getColumnText(Object element, int columnsIndex)`, where `element` is an instance of L1/L2/L3, and `columnIndex` coincides with the value column.</strike>

**My solution**: Depending on what instance the `element` object is, I look up and/or down to see if the values conicide. If they do, I don't display the text on `element` level. The code is specific to my project, so I can't post any because it will make the question much harder. But if you reaaaaaallllllyyyy insist, I could write a pseudocode of it.

**Question**: I feel like this isn't very optimal (applying algorithm on each `getColumnText` call). Is there any chance of generalization of this algorithm? Or maybe should I move it outside the label provider and keep those 'values' in a map or such?

Comment: I assume you're using SWT/JFace. Usually the tree caches the values from the label provider and only update them it 'refresh' or 'update' is called on a particular node. You can easily test this by adding som e sys-outs to your code. The question is if you also automatically update the parent node label if a child changes?

Comment: @isnot2bad Yes, it is a JFace tree. That's the point, the parent doesn't update itself while going through the table, rather it calculates (from the input directly; input structure mimics a tree L1->L2->L3) which value should it have (or none) on each pass. No updating of the table is involved.

Comment: I did not fully understand your initial question: Do all nodes have values or only the leafs? And if parents can have a value too, what happens, if the parent has a different value than its children (e.g. parent has 2, all children have value 5). What is then the label of the parent?

Comment: @isnot2bad Oh, you've found a flaw in my question. I got lost in the details. Only leaves have values, the parents just display information based on leaves.

Comment: I don't know `JFace`, but this is a classic post-order tree traversal problem.  You visit nodes after their children, passing needed information as a return value, which is therefore available at the parent.  In your case this is either `null` signifying that all child values were represented at the child nodes, or it's a non-null saying all children had this value and it still needs to be represented. So the question is how to implement post-order visits in `JFace`.

Comment: @Gene That would be my last resort, if it is proven that a post-order algorithm with JFace's `LabelProvider` is less efficient than your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialize a dictionary `D`, which we'll use to store the results.

Suppose we're at a node `n`. Define `Value(n)` as follows:

- If `n` is a leaf node, **return its value**.
- Suppose `n` has children `c0, c1, .., c(k-1)`.
- Set `firstChildValue = Value(c0)`.
- For each `int i = 1, i <= k-1` in turn, do the following:

  - If `firstChildValue == Value(ci)`, do nothing.
  - If `firstChildValue != Value(ci)`: if `firstChildValue` is non-null, add all children `c1, .., c{i-1}` to `D` with the value `firstChildValue`. Then add each child `ci, .., c{k-1}` with a non-null `Value(ci)` to `D` with said value. **Return** `null`,  as `n` has children of different values.
- **Return** `firstChildValue`, as all children have the same value.

To execute this, call `Value(root)`, and add `root` to the dictionary if `Value(root)` is non-null.

I think this is the best you can do, as it evaluates each node exactly once and adds only the necessary nodes to the dictionary.

E: Thanks to @GGrec for helping me debug this. This has been an education in checking things before I share them with others.

Comment: Cool! Now, it works to a certain point. I have to debug the code to see where values are lost. The case that fails: `[root=node1,node2,node3; node1=node11,node12; node2=node21; node3=node31,node32,node33]` with leaf values `[1,2,1,1,2,1]` in that order. It starts outputting only null after the first branch.

Comment: Values are output from the dictionary, by the way.

Comment: Dictionary is filled with the leaves of the first subtree (node11=1, node12=2), but that's it. The rest are not there. I have to really be careful translating your algorithm to Java, since the collections are zero-indexed.

Comment: How much of a newbie are you with programming? Java in particular. Here's my translation of your algorithm http://pastebin.com/q7wrgHn6 - if you have a dev environment set up, and if you're brave enough, you could just paste it into Eclipse and run it to see a visual feedback. :-)

Comment: Aight, here's the code: http://pastebin.com/BddG9Ujr. You were missing the value of `node21` in your test data, which confused me, but it seems to be working. Updating the post now (edit: wrong code the first time)

Comment: Sorry for that, I was really tired. But beautiful work! You're now the go-to guy for algorithm questions. Good job, and keep up the good work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should ignore performance at first. Instead try to be as generic as possible. Write two different label provider implementations, that do not rely on your internal data structure but can work with other `ILabelProvider` and `ITreeContentProvider` instances:

1. The `SummarizingLabelProvider` will pull common labels up the tree, so if a subtrees leaves have identical labels, it will return this label for all nodes of this subtree.
2. The `IgnoreDetailsLabelProvider` will ignore child labels if the parent already has the same label.

**`SummarizingLabelProvider#getText(element)`**

Recursively looks at the children of the tree (using content provider): If all children have the same text, return this text, otherwise return the original text of the element (by using the other label provider). Needs another `ILabelProvider` and the `ITreeContentProvider` as constructor arguments.

**`IgnoreDetailsLabelProvider#getText(element)`**

Returns `null`, if the other label provider returns the same text for the element and for its parent. Needs another `ILabelProvider` and the `ITreeContentProvider` as constructor arguments.

Now you can chain your label providers:

```
ILabelProvider lp1 = // original label provider
ILabelProvider lp2 = new SummarizingLabelProvider(contentProvider, lp1);
ILabelProvider lp3 = new IgnoreDetailsLabelProvider(contentProvider, lp2);

treeViewer.setLabelProvider(lp3);
```

**Performance**

The most performance intense label provider is the `SummarizingLabelProvider`. For every `getText(element)`, it has to traverse the subtree of `element` in the worst case. You can optimize it by using a `Map` that caches previously calculated texts. But before doing so, you should really test if initial performance is too low!

The `IgnoreDetailsLabelProvider` just calls the underlying `SummarizingLabelProvider` two times per `getText`, so it will profit from the cache too.

Comment: But then how will this affect other data in the table? There are quite a few other columns present. Also, will this method imply switching label providers on the fly? And I'm not sure I need the content provider per se in those custom label providers since my input is structured as a tree already (input is wrapped in a so-called `CustomModelTree`, where each node consists of itself and a payload).

Comment: Instead of having one TableLabelProvider for the entire table, you can also set individual label providers on the columns instead. This is the suggested approach.

Comment: If you want to skip the content provider and directly use the underlying tree structure instead, you can do so. But then the two label providers will not be model independent any more.

Comment: Uh Oh.. I'm kind of reluctant to the whole label provider for each column method. System standard and whatnot.